# PDF Spec - ExtGState

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

What does this ExtGState object do to an image:

```
<< /Type /ExtGState /TR /Identity >>
```

I have the PDF spec, but it is not clear at all. Apparently this maps the identity function (identity of what? the identity matrix?) from [0.0 1.0] to [0.0 1.0] (the same), which makes no sense.

Could someone please explain to me what this does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It specifies a function that should be used for processing colors or color components (e.g. for gamma correction). Specifying `/Identity` should actually be the same as not specifying it at all (it's an optional field), so I'd suspect that the software that produced the PDF just always writes a default `ExtGState` object for simplicity's sake.

See the chapter on Transfer Functions in the PDF spec for more information.